# Use PKCS#11 for SSH connection to the server to make token dependency

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, pkcs

I have configured `PKCS#11` remote ssh connection on my Ubuntu server such that users can login to it using a hardware token, as described [here](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1523343). However, in this condition, the user can login to the server and remove the token and give it to someone else for login. I want to restrict the user such that when he removes the token, he could not keep the connection to my server anymore (or after a short time). E.g. I want to configure continuous dependency on the token. Is it necessary to develop a specific SSH client? Currently, I use [Putty-CAC](https://github.com/NoMoreFood/putty-cac) as the client.

Comment: Are your clients using Windows or Linux?

Comment: @user1686: They are using Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible without client modifications – user authentication in SSH is performed only once for the entire connection, as well as being client-initiated in the first place.

SSHv2 does support *rekeying*, which may even be server-initiated, but it only creates a dependency on the server's "host" keypair, not the user's.

Though the "gssapi-keyex" mechanism might be an exception as it merges Kerberos user authentication into the key exchange method and therefore depends on the user having non-expired Kerberos tickets, but if you're using PKCS#11 then you're not using Kerberos.

(I could also think of a hack that involves loading your PKCS#11 token into Pageant-CAC (PuTTY's SSH key agent), then enabling SSH "agent forwarding" so that the server could periodically request signatures from the forwarded agent... but this of course has the *massive* downside of allowing the PKCS#11 token to be abused by malicious servers through the same "agent forwarding" feature.)

Maybe treat it as a company policy problem and impose consequences on account sharing.